Prevent screensaver from locking device
I am looking for a way to prevent the screensaver from locking the device. Currently I have set the "Sleep" (screensaver) to 15 seconds wich means that the screen fades after about 15 seconds and locks then. I still want to keep the fade behavior but I dont want that the device gets locked after that time. I just want it to stay in the faded state and "wakes up" again after I tap the screen.
I am currently using a rootet Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 3G 10.1 with Android 8.1.0 installed.

Could you check the Security settings, whether there's something like "Auto lock when screen turns off"?
